# error:TS2345 [ERROR]:Argument of type '"any" | "access" | "create" | "modify" | "remove" | "other"' is not assignable to prameter of type 'FileAction'

Tags: dotenv, deno

I tried to install `denon` using the following command on Windows CMD

```
deno install -qAf --unstable https://deno.land/x/denon/denon.ts
```

But I get the following error:

```
error: TS2345 [ERROR]: Argument of type '"any" | "access" | "create" | "modify" | "remove" | "other"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FileAction'.
  Type '"other"' is not assignable to type 'FileAction'.
            this.#changes[path].push(kind);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Denon installation failed in Deno v1.18.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70813752/denon-installation-failed-in-deno-v1-18-0)