# Denon installation failed in Deno v1.18.0

Tags: nodemon, deno

I tried installing `denon` for running my deno script

I used the following command from their [docs](https://github.com/denosaurs/denon#denoland),

```sh
deno install -qAf --unstable https://deno.land/x/denon/denon.ts
```

And the command failed with,

```
error: TS2345 [ERROR]: Argument of type '"any" | "access" | "create" | "modify" | "remove" | "other"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FileAction'.
  Type '"other"' is not assignable to type 'FileAction'.
            this.#changes[path].push(kind);
                                     ~~~~
    at https://deno.land/x/denon@2.4.10/src/watcher.ts:150:38
```

P.S. If this is an expected behavior is there any alternative for `denon`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** This issue has been fixed in [denon v2.5.0](https://github.com/denosaurs/denon/releases/tag/2.5.0)

**Original answer:**

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/denosaurs/denon/issues/155) in `denon`, an official fix will be released soon but in the meantime there is a patch which you can install to workaround the issue, see [this comment on GitHub](https://github.com/denosaurs/denon/issues/155#issuecomment-980478276):

```
deno install -qAf --unstable https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nnmrts/denon/patch-4/denon.ts
```

You can also downgrade to a version released before the bug was introduced.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have `nodemon`, you do not need `denon` at all.
`nodemon` can watch for file changes and restart the `deno` process for you.

Consider a dev command below, adjust the deno arguments as needed.

```
nodemon --watch src --signal SIGHUP --exec deno run --allow-all --unstable --inspect src/index.ts
```